# How can I tell if a cat is depressed?

Tags: cats, behavior, psychology

My cat, who is about 2.5 years old, is awake most of the night, when none of the family is, and asleep -- seemingly resigned -- during most of the day. I feel sorry for him. Wouldn't he be lonely at night?

He used to like playing with toys, but not so much anymore. Now, he mostly just likes to lie down underneath the coffee table. I don't know what he thinks about.

He used to be a social cat. He loves being around people. He's still social, but I feel like I don't have any chances to interact with him, apart from when I pull out the treat bag, or when it's time for food. Apart from that, we just sit and stare at each other, and occasionally touch.

Could he be depressed?

Comment: How old is your cat? Cats actually sleep a huge amount of the time, it could be that he's simply no longer a kitten.

Comment: @user90 2.5 years old should be pretty active still

Comment: Cats are also naturally partly nocturnal. Being awake part of the night is entirely normal. If you want to increase interaction, find toys that let you play with each other -- string, wands, laser pointers, that sort of thing. One of mine will sometimes bring me a small ball to throw down the corridor for her to chase, though she's still figuring out that if she brings it back I'll do this again.

Comment: If you have time to stare, you have time to wave a feather wand or laser pointer or string... But remember, older cats _do_ spend less time and energy playing than youngsters do. My two 8yo's still chase each other (and imaginary things, and sometimes toys or me) around the house, but most of our -social time is just cuddling ... or them keeping an eye on me while I''m working.

Answer (score 2):

Cats aren't pack animals like dogs.  While domestic cats are one of the few cats that are non-solitary, they still naturally spend long periods of time off on their own, like while they are hunting.  Of course, how much social time an individual cat requires can vary, (siamese cats for instance, tend to be quite needy), but I find that most cats that need more will demand it.  I recommend for the night, make sure the cat has plenty of toys and such to keep entertained while you're asleep.